# Connecting EEG to arduino to control RC car

Tags: c++, arduino

I have opened up a Mind Flex eeg and soldered to the T-pin (the brain data transfer pin) and connected it to the RX pin of the arduino. I also soldered and connected a ground. I then opened the RC remote of a new bright RC car and soldered to the test points that correlated to forward and backward, as well as the power and ground.

I am very new to C++ and have been working hard for the past two months to pick it up and feel like today was really a break through where it finally made sense. I think I am having some basic syntax issues that may be solved easily by a more experienced C++ programmer.

So as of now I got it to moved based on the brain data provided by the eeg.

So what I want the code to do is...

Start up then check the signal quality of the headset.

Then perform actions based on the attention value...
First: if the attValue == 0, then move the wheels back and forth to signify no connection
Second: if  attValue > 50, then move the RC car forward
Third: if the attValue < 50, then move the RC car backward

I only want it to perform whatever action based on the attValue for maybe 1 to 2 seconds then recheck the attValue and perform an action based upon value.

I was advised to check out the BlinkWithoutDelay example to see how to recheck the code so I tried to implement that. In a separate sketch I was about to get the wheels to either jostle back and forth, go forward, or straight. I am just not 100% sure how to go about integrating that to work with serial data being received through the monitor. I have attached my code below.

A bit of extra info on the Brain library. The signal value will be between 0 and 200. 0 means a perfect signal quality while 200 means very poor eeg signal quality, well even none at all.

```
#include <Brain.h>
#define FORWARD 2
#define BACKWARD 4
#define RIGHT 7
#define LEFT 8

const byte MindFlex = 0;

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 8000;
//This first action sent will be HIGH
int moveCar = LOW;
//This first action sent will be LOW
int moveIt = HIGH;
Brain brain(Serial);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(FORWARD, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(BACKWARD, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(RIGHT, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LEFT, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MindFlex, INPUT);
    byte readSignalQuality();

 //Not getting much from this first part none if it is printing in the serial monitor
 //Look at modifying the if statements to else, else if possibly

  if (brain.update()) {
    Serial.println("You have ran 'brain.update' so can begin receiving data.");
    delay(80000);
  }

  if (brain.readSignalQuality() == 0) { 
      Serial.println("Good Connection");
      delay(2000);


  if (brain.readSignalQuality() > 0) 
      Serial.println("Need to adjust headset, you have a poor connection.");
      delay(2000);
  }

}

void loop() {
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();  
byte attValue = brain.readAttention(); 
byte sigValue = brain.readSignalQuality();
String yourAtt = "Your attention level is: ";
String yourSignal = "Your signal quality is: ";
String Signal = yourSignal + sigValue;
String Attention = yourAtt + attValue;
String moveForward = "Your Attention is > 50, and GO!";
String moveBackward = "Your Attention is < 50, back, back, BACK IT UP!";
String noAttention = "Error: Unable to receive Attention signal.";

 // brain.update(); 

//This while loop will execute continuously until the connection drops
  while (sigValue < 200) {
      Serial.println(Signal);
      Serial.println(Attention);
      delay(1000);
      //Serial.println(brain.readCSV());
  }

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
       previousMillis = currentMillis;

          if (moveCar == LOW)
            moveCar = HIGH;
          else
            moveCar = LOW;

          if (moveIt == HIGH)
            moveIt = LOW;
          else
            moveIt = HIGH;

  if (attValue == 0) 
      Serial.println(noAttention);
      //Need to solder wires to left n right to have that happen if no connection
      digitalWrite(RIGHT, moveCar);
      digitalWrite(LEFT, moveIt);

  if (attValue < 50)
       Serial.println(moveForward);
       digitalWrite(FORWARD, LOW);
       digitalWrite(BACKWARD, HIGH);    

  if (attValue > 50) 
        Serial.println(moveBackward);
        digitalWrite(BACKWARD, LOW); 
        digitalWrite(FORWARD, HIGH);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is clearly missing a number of curly braces in locations where they're required, e.g.

```
  if (attValue == 0)
      Serial.println(noAttention);
      //Need to solder wires to left n right to have that happen if no connection
      digitalWrite(RIGHT, moveCar);
      digitalWrite(LEFT, moveIt);
```

(There needs to be a `{` at the end of the first line, and a `}` after the last line.)

By some stroke of bizarre luck, you happen to have the same number of open braces as close braces, so your code *might* compile, but it won't work as intended.